# How to get the actual average, not rounded?

Tags: java, average, mean

this is what I have (changed the print message for this question), and when I do 4 and 11, you should get 7.5, but it's only giving me 7. how do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class U1_L6_Average_Finder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    int b;
    System.out.println("put in 4");
    a = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Put in 11");
    b = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Here is your average");
    System.out.print((a + b) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Use double or float instead of int.

Comment: `System.out.print( (double)(a + b) /2 );`

Comment: You could also coerce the quotient to a floating-point value by changing the `2` (denominator) to a `2.0`, `2f`, `2.0f`. If you want a double, you can use a `d` instead of an `f`.

Comment: How could I change it so that there is only one input, like a double input instead of two seperate

Answer (score 1):

You're using integers (`int a, b;`), so it will round your results.

Instead of it, use `double` or `float` to get what you want, e.g:
`double a, b;`

But, if you don't want to modify the type of your variable, you can edit your last `System.out.print` using `f` (for example), that will convert your value to `float`, e.g:

`System.out.print((a + b) / 2.0f);`

Check this to understand more about variables:
[Java Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_variables.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could coerce the quotient to a floating-point value by changing the `2` (denominator) to a `2.0`, `2f`, `2.0f`. If you want a double, you can use a `d` instead of an `f`.

```java
public class AverageFloatingPointCoercionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;

        System.out.print("Enter value #1 (4): ");
        a = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter value #2 (11): ");
        b = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Here is your average: ");
        System.out.print((a + b) / 2.0f); // 7.5
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can cast the numerator explicitly.

```java
System.out.print(((float) (a + b)) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have the input/averaging nailed. So here's the missing bit.
- Just output r...
- But if you want a certain number of decimal places (5 here)...
- I did this in case you wanted to average more than 2 items...

---

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int i = 5;
        int j = 17;
        double r = (double)i/j;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
        System.out.println(r);
        System.out.println(df.format(r));
    }
}
```

---

Outputs:

0.29411764705882354

0.29412

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer divison. Integer divison will result integer as answer. You have to change one of the values to double.

Example:

`System.out.println((double)(a+b)/2);`

or

`System.out.println((a+b)/2.0));`